# Case Statement, conversion failed when converting varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I don't know how to properly explain this.  In my Detail Table I am trying to find the Fees.  Let's say the fees all equal $10.00

What I'm trying to do is simply make the field value negative when the tranname = 'Corr Official' and the Fee.Waiver is Null .  Problem is, the field in the table is varchar.  I've tried to do a cast and a  convert with no success.

```
(Case when Detail.FieldValue = '$0.00' and tranname = 'Official' then Fee.Waiver * -1 
when TranName = 'CORR-Official ' and Fee.Waiver IS not null then Fee.Waiver 
when TranName = 'CORR-Official' and Fee.Waiver  IS null then Cast(Detail.FieldValue, int) * -1 
when Detail.FieldValue = '$0.00' and Fee.Waiver IS not null then Fee.Waiver * -1 
when Fee.Waiver IS not null then Fee.Waiver * -1 
when Detail.FieldValue is null and Fee.Waiver IS null then Detail.FieldValue     
else Detail.FieldValue end) as FieldValue
```

Here is my error:

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '$10.00' to data type int.

Comment: Why are you storing a currency value in the FieldValue?  Honestly, that's a terrible design -- a numeric value should be stored in a numeric column.  You can't convert `$0.00` to 0, because to SQL that's not a number.  Assuming you only ever have a dollar sign, and not any other currency signs, you can strip out the dollar sign before converting.

Comment: Man, if I knew that I wouldn't be here.  Don't get me started on why the heck they constructed the data this way.  It's out of my control.  User flexibility I guess...

Comment: What is the datatype of Fee.Waiver?

Comment: If FieldValue always starts with a `$` or other monetary sign, you can `replace` it with `''` (empty string), and then convert it to `int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't convert $0.00 to 0, because to SQL that's not a number.

Since the design seems to be out of your control, and assuming you only ever have a dollar sign, and not any other currency signs, you can strip out the dollar sign before converting.

On your third line, do this:

```
when TranName = 'CORR-Official' and Fee.Waiver  IS null then 
    Cast(Replace(Detail.FieldValue, '$', '') as decimal(18, 2)) * -1
```

Or if you have multiple currencies (which it doesn't look like, but hey, let's be thorough):

```
when TranName = 'CORR-Official' and Fee.Waiver  IS null then 
    Cast(RIGHT(Detail.FieldValue, len(Detail.FieldValue) - 1) as decimal(18, 2)) * -1
```

Note, however, that you'll need to convert to a decimal as well, instead of an integer, otherwise you'll get:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.00' to data type int.

That said, it's always a much better idea to normalize the data and use appropriate data types.

Comment: If you use `substring` it doesn't matter if it's dollar or pounds or yen or Hungarian florint or whatever.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - true; I did take the lazy way out here.  Edited for consistency

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6
'decimal' is not a recognized built-in function name.  the field won't have multiple currencies, but it will have other text in it without dollar signs.  For what I'm pulling in though, it shouldn't...I stress shouldn't...because lord knows it won't always

Comment: Cast(Replace(Detail.FieldValue, '$', '') as decimal(18, 2))

Comment: @NoDisplayName dropped the comma.  Well done.  I appreciate the assistance.  wouldn't have gotten that one on my own!!!

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, hate to be a bitch, but I've had problems enough with queries like this :P. The example of the Hungarian Forint wasn't taken totally at random, its abbreviated "Ft" which is 2 chars long.... sorry for nit-picking :P

Comment: @HoneyBadger - no worries, then it would be up to the user to figure out the substring appropriately.  This will get them there most of the time, and that's the price you pay for keeping currency symbols in a price field.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables it's why I have a job...so...it ain't all bad  thanks everyone.  Can you update your code to drop the comma before decimal?  then the answer is good to go

Comment: ok, so i have another question.  I had a filter that was set to pull in only the "CORR-Official" trannames.  I removed the filter and now I'm getting an error?  Why would that be?             Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: @donviti - I'm guessing it's because the CASE expression is falling through to this line `when Detail.FieldValue is null and Fee.Waiver IS null then Detail.FieldValue`, which is a varchar, but since you've previously cast values as a decimal, you'll need to cast this value as a decimal also.  All values in a CASE expression need to evaluate to the same datatype.

Comment: I just found it...there is one record with a blank ' ' it's throwing everything off.  unreal.